# How to create pivot table field to filter data from existing filtering filed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with a "State" filter. How do I create another filter, "Region", that will assign specific "State" values to define values in "Region"?

When I use the create field function in Excel, I am not able to define each region and assign to it specific states.

Comment: if I am interpreting your question correctly, you should be able to just add "Region" to the "Rows" area. You don't need to make it a filter.

Comment: The underlying dataset has two columns( for now), these are State, and Units. I am unable to create another column called Region and defining this field based on the field state. Is there a way to do this without messing with the underlying dataset?

Comment: what is the correlation between state/units and region?

Comment: State is a US state, like California, New York, etc. Units is the number of product sold in that state. The field state has all US states. The field Region will have five values, West Coast, East Coast, South, North, and Midwestern. Each region will be comprised of the states in that geography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments above, you need to create a Calculated Field. To do so:

1) Click on "Fields, Items, & Sets" in the "Calculations" tab in the "Analyze" group on the Ribbon. Select Calculated Field.

2) Name the field "Region"

3) Insert an IF formula that calculates your regions. This will be a long nested IF.

4) You can now use the field like any other field.